# How can I prevent showing the splash screen when I need it in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, splash-screen, pascalscript, issi

How can I prevent showing the splash screen when I need it?
Should I add some ISSI-code to do that?

Here is my code:

```pascal
#define ISSI_Splash "C:\InnoSetupProject\Images\client.bmp"                 
#define ISSI_Splash_T 3
#define ISSI_Splash_X 500
#define ISSI_Splash_Y 220 

[Code]
function ISSI_InitializeSetup : Boolean;
begin       
  Result := True;
  if not RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\MyApp\Client', 'LocaleID') then
    if MsgBox('Client does not exist', mbCriticalError, MB_OK) = IDOK then
      begin
        Result := False;
        { How can I prevent showing the splash screen here? }
        Exit;
      end  
end;

#define ISSI_InitializeSetup
#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI" 
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of legacy `ISSI_InitializeSetup` function, use Inno Setup 6 [event attributes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=eventattributes&anchor=eventattributes):

```pascal
[Code]
<event('InitializeSetup')>
function MyInitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin       
  Result := True;
  if not RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\MyApp\Client', 'LocaleID') then
    if MsgBox('Client does not exist', mbCriticalError, MB_OK) = IDOK then
      begin
        Result := False; 
      end;
end;
```

and remove this:

```
#define ISSI_InitializeSetup
```

---

The `MyInitializeSetup` will be called before the ISSI `InitializeSetup`. And if it returns `False`, the ISSI won't ever be called, so no splash screen will show.

Check the documentation for [Event Attributes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=eventattributes&anchor=eventattributes):

> - The implementations will be called in order of their definition except that any **main implementation (=the implementation without an event attribute) will be called last**.
> - If the event function has a return value then lazy evaluation is performed:
>   `InitializeSetup`, `BackButtonClick`, `NextButtonClick`, `InitializeUninstall`:
>
>   - All implementations must return True for the event function to be treated as returning True and **an implementation returning False stops the calls to the other implementations.**

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you!